# DirectX で CreateDevice 関数を使ってフューチャーレベルが指定できない。nullになる理由と対処法が知りたい

Tags: c++, directx

`///` コメント部の内部の関数CreateDevice();関数ですがどんなフューチャーレベルを指定しても_devがnullになってしまいその後の_dev変数の参照でnull参照になってしまいプログラムを継続できません、これはなぜでしょうか？

公式リファレンスを何度も見ましたが何も悪くないと思われます。for文でいろんなフューチャーレベルを探す仕組みにしましたがどれも合わないみたいです。またデバッグログを出力しましたがわかりません。エラーコードを調べましたが対処すればいいのでしょうか？

**出力結果**

```
 0    887a0004

 1    80070057
 2    80070057
 3    80070057
 4    80070057
 5    80070057

 6    887a0004
 7    887a0004
 8    887a0004
 9    887a0004
```

参考サイト1: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-d3d12createdevice
参考サイト2: https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-iid_ppv_args
参考サイト3(win32エラーコード一覧): http://ir9.jp/prog/ayu/win32err.htm

API: DirectX12
提示画像はdxdiagによるスペック表示です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
#pragma comment(lib,"d3d12.lib")

#pragma comment(lib,"dxgi.lib")

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winerror.h>

#include <d3d12.h>

#include <dxgi1_4.h>
#include <dxgi.h>

#include <dxgi1_5.h>
#include <dxgi1_6.h>
#include <combaseapi.h>
#include <d3dcommon.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#endif
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void DebugOutputFormatString(const char* format)
//void DebugOutputFormatString(const char* format,...)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    va_list valist;
    va_start(valist, format);
    vprintf(format, valist);
    va_end(valist);
#endif
}

LRESULT WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wparam,LPARAM lparam)
{
    if(msg == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,msg,wparam,lparam);

}

/*feature level 配列*/
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL levels[] = {//10

  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_1_0_CORE,

  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1,
  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,

  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,

  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,

  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0,
  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1

//  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1,

};

ID3D12Device* _dev = nullptr;

IDXGIFactory6* _dxgiFactory = nullptr;
IDXGISwapChain4* _swapchain = nullptr;

#ifdef _DEBUG
int main()
{

#else 
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE,HINSTANCE,LPSTR,int)
{
#endif

    //ID3D12Device::CheckFeatureSupport();
//  CheckFeatureSupport(D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0,IID_PPV_ARGS(&_dev));


    /*フューチャーレベルを設定*/
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
    int t = 0;
    //for(auto lv : levels)
    for(auto lv : levels)
    {

        //HRESULT h = D3D12CreateDevice(nullptr, lv, IID_PPV_ARGS(&_dev));
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        HRESULT h = D3D12CreateDevice(nullptr, lv, IID_PPV_ARGS(&_dev));
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if ( h == S_OK)
        {
            featureLevel = lv;
            cout<<"成功です"<<std::endl;
            break;

        }else
        {
        //  printf("%ld\n",h);
            printf(" %d    %lx\n",t,h);
            t++;
        }

    }

    if(_dev == nullptr )
    {
        printf("null");
        //exit(1);
        //return -1;
    }

    /*アダプタを設定*/
    auto result = CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(&_dxgiFactory));
    if(result != S_OK)
    {
        //return -1;
    }
    std::vector<IDXGIAdapter*> adapters;
    IDXGIAdapter* tmpAdapter = nullptr;
    for(int i = 0; _dxgiFactory->EnumAdapters(i,&tmpAdapter) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND; i++)
    {
        adapters.push_back(tmpAdapter);
    }

    for(auto adpt : adapters)
    {
        DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC adesc = {  };
        adpt->GetDesc(&adesc);
        std::wstring strDesc = adesc.Description;
        if(strDesc.find(L"INTEL") != std::string::npos)
        {
            printf("aaaa");
            tmpAdapter = adpt;
            break;
        }

    }

    WNDCLASSEX w = {};
    w.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    w.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WindowProcedure;
    w.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);

    RegisterClassEx(&w);

    //  RECT wrc = { 0,0,window_width,window_height };
    RECT wrc = { 0,0,100,100 };//ウインドウサイズ
    AdjustWindowRect(&wrc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, false);//ウインドウサイズの補正

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(w.lpszClassName,
        TEXT("DX12テスト"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        wrc.right - wrc.left,
        wrc.bottom - wrc.top,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        w.hInstance,
        nullptr);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);

    /*コマンドキュー*/
    ID3D12CommandQueue* _cmdQueue = nullptr;

    D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_DESC cmdQueueDesc = { };
    cmdQueueDesc.Flags = D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_FLAG_NONE;
    cmdQueueDesc.NodeMask = 0;
    cmdQueueDesc.Priority = D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_PRIORITY_NORMAL;

    cmdQueueDesc.Type = D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT;
    result = _dev->CreateCommandQueue(&cmdQueueDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&_cmdQueue));

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapchainDesc = { };
    swapchainDesc.Width = (UINT)100;
    swapchainDesc.Height = (UINT)100;
    swapchainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    swapchainDesc.Stereo = false;
    swapchainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapchainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapchainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_BACK_BUFFER;
    swapchainDesc.BufferCount = 2;

    swapchainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
    swapchainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;
    swapchainDesc.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_UNSPECIFIED;
    swapchainDesc.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;

    result = _dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(_cmdQueue, hwnd, &swapchainDesc, nullptr, nullptr, (IDXGISwapChain1**)&_swapchain);
    if(result == S_OK)
    {
    }

    printf("S_OK\n");

    MSG msg = {  };
    while (true) {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    UnregisterClass(w.lpszClassName, w.hInstance);

    //DebugOutputFormatString("show window test.");
    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: 返された`HRESULT`の値について議論すべきだと思います。ちなみに私の環境では`S_OK`が得られました。

Comment: そうですが自分の環境ではどれもelse文の文字列が配列で設定されている分coutされておりますが何か違うのでしょうか？ HRESULTの値を確認しましたがすべてS_OK以外の値になっています。

Comment: あくまでもHRESULTの値を秘匿するのであれば第三者には何もわからないと思います。ご自身で調査されることをお勧めします。

Comment: 指摘通りHRESULTの値を出力して表示しました。提示コードを編集しました。

Comment: 画像でなく文字で入力してください。

Comment: HRESULTの値を検索ワードにしてネットで検索すると、値の意味を調べることができます。ここ(https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/direct3d12/d3d12-graphics-reference-returnvalues)　とかここ(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/dxgi-error)　 の内容でプログラムを見直されてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 文章にエラーコードを載せました。また提示提示されたサイトでエラーコードを調べましたが。DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED
0x887A0004
要求された機能は、デバイスまたはドライバーでサポートされていません。と書かれているのですがこれはどう対処すればいいのでしょうか？6 ~ 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

お使いの[Intel HD Graphics 4000](https://www.intel.co.jp/content/www/jp/ja/support/articles/000005524/graphics-drivers.html)はDirectX11にしか対応していません。そのために、[`DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED` 0x887A0004](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/dxgi-error#DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED)が返されています。HRESULTの値は常に確認すべきです。

DirectX12未対応デバイスでDirect3D 12を使用するには、WARP software deviceを使用する必要があります。具体的なコード例は[D3D12CreateDeviceのexample](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-d3d12createdevice#examples)に書かれています。

もう一方のエラーは[`E_INVALIDARG` 0x80070057](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/common-hresult-values)で引数が誤っている旨を指摘しています。